# What's so special about quadratic extensions?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, quadratics

Reading through chapter 13 "Field Theory" from Dummit and Foote Algebra.

I am wondering why such an emphasis is placed upon "quadratic extensions" of a field F.  They state that for any field F (ch(F) not 2) all degree 2 extensions have the form F(squarerootD) read "F adjoin the square root of D" where D is not the square of another element of F.

Does an analogous statement for degree 3 extensions hold? For degree n? Even if those analogous statements do NOT hold for other degrees, am I missing something else about why this statement is important?

Thanks for the help!   See below for the text reference:
[image]

Comment: NONE of those statements holds for extensions of degree $>2$. The upshot is that quadratic extensions are easy to run examples on, the other extensions not so much.

Comment: What do you mean they are easy to run examples on?  Can you give an example? @Lubin

Comment: I was thinking of algebraic number theory, where it’s very easy to determine which numbers in the extension field are algebraic integers; and beyond that very easy to find the units in the ring of algebraic integers, and to see how the primes of $\mathbb Z$ split in the ring of integers upstairs. More!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where they used these facts about all degree two extensions.  Since all degree two extensions take this form described above, all degree two extensions are Galois (meaning they have full automorphism group).  That is already significant, but then they used that fact to show a somewhat surprising result that Galois extensions of a Galois extension need not be Galois.  See below:

[image]